# Src link and equals sign dissapearing

Tags: php, html, image, equals, src

I am dynamically grabbing image links from a database and inserting them into image tags.  This php code checks if there is a link or not.  If there is a link, that link is inserted into the img code.  If there is no link, a generic "image coming soon" picture is used in its place.

```
echo '<tr>
                <td width="80" height="46">
                <a href="displayitem.php?item_id='.$top_product_id.'">';
                if (!is_null($top_link) || $top_link == "")
                {
                    echo'<img src = "'.$top_link.'" alt="" width="64" height="63" />';
                    //echo $top_link;
                }
                else
                {
                    echo'<img src = "imagen/imagecomingsoon.png" alt="" width="30%" height="40%" />';}
                echo'</td><td width="108"><a href="displayitem.php?item_id='.$top_product_id.'">'.$final_name.'</a>';
                echo'</td>
                </tr>';
```

I have a strange bug that in the event there is no image to link, instead of using the generic image, I get a blank.  When I inspect the blank box, I see that the img tag is not generating properly.  There are no quotes, or even an equals sign after the src designation.  It looks like this.

```
<img src alt="" width="64" height="63">
```

Whey would the entire equals sign dissapear along with the quotes and link in the event I want to use a generic image?

Comment: try dumping the $top_link before IF, what do you get?

Comment: Cannot reproduce with PHP 5.3.10, Firefox 14. Is there different output if you do not use white space around the equal sign?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `!is_null($top_link) || $top_link == ""` with `!is_null($top_link) && $top_link != ""`. But i would replace the whole condition:

```
if (!empty($top_link)) {
    echo '<img src = ......';
}
```

This would let you not care about different types of emptiness in php.

Comment: This did the trick.  Using the empty function improved my code in other places too.

Answer (score 0):

After inspecting your code I guess your IF Condition is going wrong, try this

> if (!is_null($top_link) || $top_link != " ")

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion but i am not sure that's the problem

Try this : `echo'<img src = '".$top_link."' alt="" width="64" height="63" />';`

i put the ' before the "

And replace the || with &&